# Moving layers by half pixel (GIMP)

Tags: gimp

Is it possible (and how) to move a layer by half pixel (or other float values). I'm drawing a small image where moving a single pixel is too noticeable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Increase (scale) the size of the entire image by 2 in both vertical and horizontal dimensions. This will result in an *exact* scale, where every single pixel in the original image is now four pixels (2x2) in the new image. Now shift the layer over 1 pixel, and then scale the entire image back down to the original size. Make sure the image supports anti-aliasing before down-scaling.

Additionally, having already scaled up, you may want to keep the higher resolution for any other edits until it's time to prepare the final version for publishing.

Comment: I was about to suggest moving 1 pixel and halfing the intensity of it, and fiddling with it from there. But your method accomplishes it undoubtedly more accurately and easily. Nice!

Comment: Nice. The result after linear interpolation is a slightly blurry, but the Sharpen filter fixed that up.

Comment: When upscaling, don't use interpolation. That way you'll get more accurate results. @LieRyan

Comment: This technique worked great in paint.net also.